# Traditional wine recommendation for a romantic evening on Valentine's Day?

Tags: recommendations, wine, tradition

Being a man of tradition and enjoying the finer things in life, I would like to have a nice romantic evening with my love next Valentine's Day (February 14).

However I would like to keep the choice of wine in keeping with a few points of Tradition.

February 14 is in the Catholic world the Feast of [St Valentine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Valentine) (226-269),from where we get the traditions involved with [Valentine's Day](http://www.history.com/topics/valentines-day/history-of-valentines-day) as well the Feast of [St Vincent of Saragossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_of_Saragossa), who died in 304.

Both of these saints were martyred for their faith. St Valentine was a bishop and is the [Patron Saint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patron_saint) of lovers and marriage. St Vincent was a deacon and is considered the Patron Saint of winemakers.

In keeping with the above information could anyone recommend a good traditional minded wine for a romantic evening on Valentine's Day?

Comment: If it isn't a first date, you should have some inkling of what you both really like. Choose something on the higher quality side of that list and drink that.

Comment: Just reading the news and I saw this article, I know it doesn't answer the question but might be of interest regarding St. Valentine.  http://www.express.co.uk/news/history/766657/Saint-Valentine-3D-technology-brought-back-life

Comment: A budget friendly suggestion, that you wouldn't anyway taste everyday is a nice [Rosso di Montalcino](https://g.co/kgs/JeFRUx). But how to relate it with saints?? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're planning well ahead, good man, I'd suggest you pair your celebration with the Umbria, as he was Valentinus of Terni, in central Italy. Poor man, bits of him, his relics, are in churches all over, in Dublin, as well as in Rome and Savona, Madrid, Prague, Vienna, Birmingham, Glasgow, Malta, Greece, and France.

Umbrian truffi, truffles, suggests strangozzi (pasta) with black truffles, paired with Montefalco Sagrantino, or gallina ubriaca, drunken hen, a chicken cooked wine; cook it in Montefalco Rosso and, what else, pair it Montefalco Rosso (after all, you don't want to cook with a wine you wouldn't drink).

And then there's Perugia, the capitol of Umbria, and Perugina Baci, kisses, chocolate, how appropriate. Pair that with an Orvieto Classico or Grechetto Bianco.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't Saint Valentine Irish? I would be drinking a Guinness then! Oh, but you asked for wine... You could celebrate with the blood of Christ and drink a nice Italian Red Wine, like a nice aged [Amarone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarone). But really this is a celebration and that calls for [CHAMPAGNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne)!

Comment: St Valentine was a Roman martyr, but the origins of [Valentine's Day](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15254a.htm) is from either England or France.